# Tap gesture events on overlapping area

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a view that is with the black border and it has two different views on it. And these views are overlapping in a small area. And each of them has own UITapGestureRecognizer. When I tap each item's discrete area, the action of that item is triggered. But when I tap the common area, only the second view's action is triggered. I want that both actions have to be triggered. How can I achieve this? Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var outerView: UIView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      outerView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
      outerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
      view1.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
      view1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
      view2.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
      view2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
      self.initialize()
  }

  private func initialize(){
      let tapGesture1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(detectTap1(_:)))
      let tapGesture2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(detectTap2(_:)))
      self.view1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture1)
      self.view2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture2)
  }

  @objc func detectTap1(_ gesture : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
      print("detectTap1")
  }

  @objc func detectTap2(_ gesture : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
      print("detectTap2")
  }
}
```

[image: example]

Kindly share your suggestions.

Comment: check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this problem i have found this solution, maybe is not the best solution but it works, i will look for further improvements anyway

I had subclassed `UIGestureRecognizer` class

## Updated

```
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

class CustomGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {

    var anotherGestureRecognizer : CustomGestureRecognizer?
    private var touchBeganSended : Bool = false
    private var touchLocation : CGPoint?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        if let validTouch = touches.first?.location(in: self.view) {
            if (self.view!.point(inside: validTouch, with: event)) {
                if(!touchBeganSended) {
                    touchBeganSended = true
                    touchLocation = validTouch
                    anotherGestureRecognizer?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
                    state = .recognized
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        if let validTouch = touches.first?.location(in: self.view) {
            if (self.view!.point(inside: validTouch, with: event)) {
                if(touchBeganSended) {
                    touchBeganSended = false
                    anotherGestureRecognizer?.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
                    state = .recognized
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func location(in view: UIView?) -> CGPoint {
        if let desiredView = view {
            if(desiredView == self.view) {
                return touchLocation ?? CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            } else {
                return super.location(in: view)
            }
        } else {
            return super.location(in: view)
        }
    }
}
```

## Updated

then you need to modify your `initialize()` method to this one, with the last **update** ***you don't need to take into account which view is on top on view hierarchy***

```
private func initialize(){
    let tapGesture1 = CustomGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(detectTap1(_:)))
    let tapGesture2 = CustomGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(detectTap2(_:)))
    tapGesture1.cancelsTouchesInView = true
    tapGesture1.delegate = self
    tapGesture2.cancelsTouchesInView = true
    tapGesture2.delegate = self
    self.view1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture1)
    tapGesture1.anotherGestureRecognizer = tapGesture2
    tapGesture2.anotherGestureRecognizer = tapGesture1
    self.view2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture2)
}
```

this works as you can see here

[image]

Comment: @Ahmet my  answer was updated, now you don't have to take in account which view is on top, please check it kindly, happy coding

Comment: Quick question. When I tap the common area, the location of the anotherGestureRecognizer is 0,0. But it is not true. Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: @Ahmet problem solved, check my updated answer and let me know

Comment: You're the man. I really appreciated. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
private func initialize(){

        let tapGesture1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(detectTap1(_:)))
        let tapGesture2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(detectTap2(_:)))
        tapGesture1.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        tapGesture2.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.view1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture1)
        self.view2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture2)
 }
```

When you set

> gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false

it propagates the gesture to the views underneath.

Comment: Hi. I tried but it did not work, when I tapped the common area, it just printed "detectTap2" not both.

Comment: Can you write the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** method:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

... 
...

private func initialize() {
...
  gesture1.delegate = self
  gesture2.delegate = self
...
}

func gestureRecognizer(
_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
 shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer
) -> Bool {
    // its up to you 
    //guard otherGestureRecognizer == yourAnotherGesture else { return false }
    return true
}
```

Comment: I have no parent gesture?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Actually not parentGesture, you should compare with your another gesture. For example if gesture 1 is recognized, you should type:

```guard otherGestureRecognizer == gesture2 else { return false }```.

Actually, you can try just try 
```return true```
 without anything else.

Comment: I tried, but it did not work. It still prints "detectTap2" when I tap the common area.

Comment: did you write: ```tapGesture1.delegate = self``` and ```tapGesture2.delegate = self``` ?